# How to force download a file in PHP with multi-parallel download?

Tags: php, file, streaming, download

How to force download a file in PHP with multi-parallel download ?
I attempt to open a stream force download a file using header and readfile successfully but It supports only 1 parallel (1 connection) and can not resume downloading file anytime.

Please help me a suggestion !

Comment: Are you using sessions? If so, search for similar questions about downloading and sessions.

Comment: I'm not using sessions, just force downloading some big file.